# Generate makefile targets from a list of source files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a build system using make and would like to do the following:

have a list of source files specified in the makefile, e.g.

```
SOURCES = a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
```

Automatically create build targets that depend on each file separately

I.e a single rule that would automatically expand into:

```
a.o: a.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o a.o

b.o: b.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c b.cpp -o b.o

c.o: c.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c c.cpp -o c.o
```

I've tried the following:

```
SOURCES = a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

However, this seems to expand into the following

```
a.o: a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o a.o

b.o: b.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o b.o

c.o: c.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o c.o
```

Which is not right

Is there a simple way to achieve the result that i wrote earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make already has built-in rules that convert a `.cpp` file to a `.o` file.  Just write:

```
SOURCES = a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp

all: $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

and it will work.  If you want to know how to write your own rules, read about [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html), in particular [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html).